# How do you inner join, left join AND full join in one query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join

I'm writing a web api in C# and I have a complicated SQL query to do in my get method. I've received an SQL file from a co-worker (who isn't here or reachable right now) which contains this:

```
FROM orsrg ors WITH (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN orkrg ork WITH (NOLOCK) ON ork.ordernr = ors.ordernr
 LEFT JOIN cicmpy c1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON ork.debnr = c1.debnr
 LEFT JOIN cicmpy c2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON ork.fakdebnr = c2.debnr
 LEFT JOIN cicmpy c3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON ork.verzdebnr = c3.debnr
 FULL JOIN humres h with (nolock) on h.res_id = ork.represent_id
```

So far, here's the C#-code that I have for this:

```
// This "using" is used to make the tables in the SQL query run as "WITH (NOLOCK)" ! (IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)

using (var txn = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
    }
))
{
    // Your LINQ to SQL query goes here
    var query = (from ors in _context.Orsrg
                 join ork in _context.Orkrg on ors.Ordernr equals ork.Ordernr
                 join c1 in _context.Cicmpy.DefaultIfEmpty() on ork.Debnr equals c1.Debnr
                 join c2 in _context.Cicmpy.DefaultIfEmpty() on ork.Fakdebnr equals c2.Debnr
                 join c3 in _context.Cicmpy.DefaultIfEmpty() on ork.Verzdebnr equals c3.Debnr
                 // FULL JOIN MUST COME HERE
                 );
}
```

As you can see, i've inner joined tables ors & ork and then did three left joins on tables c1, c2, c3 (all from Cicmpy though). So all that's left is the full join.

I've found following code also here on stackoverflow (this isn't my code):

```
var firstNames = new[]
{
    new { ID = 1, Name = "John" },
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Sue" },
};
var lastNames = new[]
{
    new { ID = 1, Name = "Doe" },
    new { ID = 3, Name = "Smith" },
};
var leftOuterJoin = from first in firstNames
                    join last in lastNames
                    on first.ID equals last.ID
                    into temp
                    from last in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new { first.ID, Name = default(string) })
                    select new
                    {
                        first.ID,
                        FirstName = first.Name,
                        LastName = last.Name,
                    };
var rightOuterJoin = from last in lastNames
                     join first in firstNames
                     on last.ID equals first.ID
                     into temp
                     from first in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new { last.ID, Name = default(string) })
                     select new
                     {
                         last.ID,
                         FirstName = first.Name,
                         LastName = last.Name,
                     };
var fullOuterJoin = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);
```

That code is doing the full outer join by partitioning it in 2 halves, once he does left outer join, once right outer join & then puts them together in one variable.

I have no idea how I could do this in my original C#-code where now it says

```
// FULL JOIN MUST COME HERE
```

These SQL queries are a lot harder than in school...

Comment: First of all this is not MySQL, it's SQL Server so you have to change the tag. What do you want to do? Convert that query to a LINQ query?

Comment: The `let` keyword is super useful here.  `let p = (some query)`

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm apparently union all is equivalent also

Comment: Edited the tag, what I need is that SQL query in c# linq to sql, in particular how to do the full join together with inner join & 3 left joins.

Comment: Slight detour...http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Note that the fullOuterJoin is not actually equivalent to the `Union` of a leftOuterJoin and a rightOuterJoin when duplicates may be involved because union removes duplicates. It should be a leftOuterJoin `Concat`ed with a rightantisemijoin (`Concat` does not remove duplicates).

Comment: Thanks, there might be duplicates so to be safe I'll concat :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some (somewhat) complicated extension methods will implement the full outer join for `AsQueryable` and translate to SQL, though perhaps not as efficiently as calling SQL directly with `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

First the extensions (there are some variations for `IEnumerable` in another answer here):

```
private static Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>> CastSMBody<TP, TC, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TP unusedP, TC unusedC, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>>)ex;

public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

    var sampleAnonLR = new { left = (TLeft)null, rightg = (IEnumerable<TRight>)null };
    var parmP = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLR.GetType(), "p");
    var parmC = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRight), "c");
    var argLeft = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmP, "left");
    var newleftrs = CastSMBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, argLeft, parmC), parmP, parmC), sampleAnonLR, (TRight)null, (TResult)null);

    return leftItems.AsQueryable().GroupJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, (left, rightg) => new { left, rightg }).SelectMany(r => r.rightg.DefaultIfEmpty(), newleftrs);
}

private static Expression<Func<TParm, TResult>> CastSBody<TParm, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TParm unusedP, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TParm, TResult>>)ex;

public static IQueryable<TResult> RightAntiSemiJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

    var sampleAnonLgR = new { leftg = (IEnumerable<TLeft>)null, right = (TRight)null };
    var parmLgR = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLgR.GetType(), "lgr");
    var argLeft = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TLeft));
    var argRight = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmLgR, "right");
    var newrightrs = CastSBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, argLeft, argRight), parmLgR), sampleAnonLgR, (TResult)null);

    return rightItems.GroupJoin(leftItems, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (right, leftg) => new { leftg, right }).Where(lgr => !lgr.leftg.Any()).Select(newrightrs);
}

public static IQueryable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

    return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Concat(leftItems.RightAntiSemiJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
}
```

You can then create your query. I had to modify it since you had the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` emulation incorrect. Also, I had to put in a select since their is no query comprehension syntax for full outer join and I didn't want to translate the rest of your query to lambda syntax.

NOTE: Your transaction will not do what you want since the creation of the `query` variable does not actually call the database. You need to do something to pull results from the `query` for the transaction (`NOLOCK` work around) to effect the query on SQL.

```
var query = (from ors in _context.Orsrg
             join ork in _context.Orkrg on ors.Ordernr equals ork.Ordernr
             join c1 in _context.Cicmpy on ork.Debnr equals c1.Debnr into c1j
             from c1 in c1j.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join c2 in _context.Cicmpy on ork.Fakdebnr equals c2.Debnr into c2j
             from c2 in c2j.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join c3 in _context.Cicmpy on ork.Verzdebnr equals c3.Debnr into c3j
             from c3 in c3j.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { ors, ork, c1, c2, c3 })
             .FullOuterJoin(_context.Humres, left => left.ork.represent_id, h => h.res_id, (_, left, h) => new { left.ors, left.ork, left.c1, left.c2, left.c3, h });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what exactly do I have to change in all the Expression methods to make my code work? Right now I get an error on

    "return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(" where it says "IQueryable<TLeft> does not contain a definition for "LeftOuterJoin" and no extension method accepting a first argument of type IQueryable<TLeft> could be found"

Comment: EDIT: nvm I think I got it, thanks a lot!! marked as answer!

Comment: EDIT again: I still get "the type argument for method FullOuterJoin(...) cannot be inferred from the usage.Try specifying the type arguments specifically", how would I go about doing this?

Comment: That indicates something is not matching in the arguments you provided to the function and so the compiler can't infer the right types.

Comment: Yeah, but I copy & pasted what you've written, in your FullOuterJoin(...) etc. and it doesn't work? In your method you need FullOuterJoin(tableLeft, tableRight, TableKey (which one?), TResult), is it perhaps that your written FullOuterJoin(_context.Humres, left => etc... is wrong or ?